# What is the syntax/parameter issue with my PowerShell script for changing a file creation date?

Tags: powershell, shell

**Problem:** I've never used PowerShell until now, but I am trying to change the creation date of a file. I used an example from the link below and below that is my PS code. I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong unless the source is wrong. It appears to be a method parameter but I'm just not sure.

Source:
[Using PowerShell to change timestamp of files and folders](https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/powershell/128/change-file-timestamp.html)

My version:

```
PS c:\Users (Get-Item "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Holiday Schedule.pdf").CreationTime=("21 November 2022 13:10:00")
```

The Error:

```
Get-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '11/22/2022 12:09:00 PM'.
At line:1 char:1
+ PS c:\Users (Get-Item "C:\Users\svallery\Desktop\RDSI 2023 Holiday Sc ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
```

Comment: does `(Get-Item ...).CreationTime = [datetime]::new(2022, 11, 21)` work?

Comment: @Santiago Squarzon Yes, this worked too. - thanks for this. My issue was including the command string as mlkement0 identified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like **you accidentally submitted part of a PowerShell *prompt string* (`PS c:\users`) as part of your command**, which explains your symptom.

Simply omit it to make your command work:<sup>[1]</sup>

```bash
(Get-Item "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Holiday Schedule.pdf").CreationTime= "21 November 2022 13:10:00"
```

When you see strings such as `PS C:\mytest>` preceding PowerShell commands in sample code (such as on the page you link to), that string is merely meant to indicate the commands are *PowerShell* commands and may be submitted from *interactive* sessions, where such strings are printed whenever the session is ready to receive a new command via interactive user input.

See also:

- The conceptual [about_Prompts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Prompts) help topic, which also discusses how to customize the prompt string.

---

<sup>[1] Note that even though a date/time *string* is assigned, PowerShell automatically converts it to a `[datetime]` object ([`System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime)), because the target property, [`.CreationTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo.CreationTime), is of that type.</sup>

Comment: That worked - excellent!! Thanks so much for the teaching moment. I bookmarked your suggested link. I don't need to do this too often but it will be a good resource.